# Append Child's Child Element

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

Is there a way to append a SimpleXML elements child's child?

For example

```
<comments>
    <comment1>
        <commentcontent>Test</commentcontent>
    </comment1>
    <comment2>
        <commentcontent>Test2</commentcontent>
        <comment3>
            <commentcontent>Test3</commentcontent>
        </comment3>
    </comment2>
</comments>
```

I want comment3 to be able to have subcomments to it. I was thinking I could use some regex or wildcard to ignore the number of the comment element but haven't been able to figure out how yet.

I was trying

```
$commentlevel = calculatelevel(($level[$commentkey] - 1)) . 'Comment' . $parent[$commentkey];
$newcomment = $commentsxml->xpath($commentlevel)->addChild('Comment' . $id);

function calculatelevel($level) {
    $compile = '';
    for($inc = 0; $inc < $level; $inc++) {
        $compile = 'Comment*/';
    }
    return $compile;
}
```

and many variations but all seem to fail. Thanks.

Comment: Why on earth are you calling the elements `comment1` and `comment2`, etc? The whole point of XML is that you can call them all `comment`.

Comment: This number is a unique identifier so each element could be selected/targeted. Would the full XML be more useful? This was a simplified version I thought would be easier to debug.

Comment: The tag name should be a "type" of element. If you need a unique identifier, it should be an `id`.

Comment: What do you mean by "tag name" and "type of element"? I don't think this is going in the right direction to answer the question...

Comment: The tag name is `comment1` vs `comment2` vs `commentcontent` vs `p` vs `br` vs `blockquote`, etc. If you name all the tags `comment`, you can have infinite nesting, and your XPath will be many times simpler.

Comment: I got this working with a regex and recreating the simplexml element. If anyone can tell me the correct way to do this though via the xpath or a regex in the simplexml element i'd appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, "normalize" your XML:

```
<comments>
    <comment id="1" content="Test">
        <comment id="2" content="Hello">
            <comment id="3" content="World">
                <comment id="4" content="It's me!" />
            </comment>
        </comment>
    </comment>
</comments>
```

Subcomments then are easy, because you don't have to take care of changing node-names:

```
$comment = $xml->xpath("//comment[@id='4']")[0]; // get comment #4 , requires PHP >= 5.4
$newcomment = $comment->addChild('comment');
$newcomment->addAttribute('id', getNewId()); // function getNewId() not specified in this example 
$newcomment->addAttribute('content', 'I am new!');
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/K1cxAq

If you have PHP < 5.4, upgrade or change this line:

```
list($comment,) = $xml->xpath("//comment[@id='4']");
```

If you can't change the XML but have to stick with it, please clarify the meaning of the number in the node-name: is it a unique identifier, or is it the level, the "depth" of the node?

Comment: Okay, let's just try basic usage, so we have:
`$xml = '<cms>
<cm id="1" cnt="Test">
<cm id="2" cnt="Hello">
<cm id="3" cnt="World">
<cm id="4" cnt="It\'s me!" />
</cm>
</cm>
</cm>
</cms>';
$simplexml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$cm = $simplexml->xpath("//cm[@id='4']")[0];
$newcm = $cm->addChild('cm');
$newcm->addAttribute('id', 5);
$newcm->addAttribute('cnt', 'con');`

but i'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line 14

Comment: Also, separate side-note code formatting in comments is terrible or i've done it wrong and wasted +300 characters.

Comment: @user1419338: yes, rather edit your question and add code there

Comment: I copy and pasted your code from that page to my server and am still getting the same error. I'm running php version 5.3.27.

Comment: Okay, I was able to get that working on my server. Swapping back to our 5.4 server though I get undefined offset, from the

    comment = $xml->xpath("//comment[@id='4']")[0]

halfway through the XML file, the element it is looking for exisits though. Is there documentation about the change between 5.3 and 5.4?